# Timezone shift and losing milliseconds when inserting dates into Oracle using the R odbc package

Tags: r, oracle, odbc

I'm switching over from using the ROracle package to using the odbc package to connect to Oracle.  Using ROracle, I was able to insert datetimes with milliseconds into a table that had a field with the timestamp data type.  Using the odbc package, milliseconds are lost.  Additionally, when I query back the date I just inserted, the time shifts four hours forward (I'm in Eastern so presumably it's shifting to UTC time).  I've confirmed the time is being inserted correctly into Oracle.  Is there an option that can be set so that milliseconds are retained and is there a way to prevent the time from shifting?

```
library(odbc)

options(digits.secs = 6)

Sys.setenv(TZ = "EST5EDT",
           ORA_SDTZ = "EST5EDT")

conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                       driver = "Oracle12c",
                       uid = rstudioapi::showPrompt(title = "username", message = "username", default = ""),
                       pwd = rstudioapi::askForPassword(),
                       dbq = "dbname",
                       timezone = Sys.timezone())

DBI::dbExecute(conn, "create table test_table (datetime timestamp(6))")

df <- data.frame(DATETIME = Sys.time(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# the time has milliseconds in R
print(df)

# insert data
res <- dbSendStatement(conn, "insert into test_table (datetime) values (:1)")
dbBind(res, df)
dbGetRowsAffected(res)
dbClearResult(res)

# the time does not have milliseconds when read back from Oracle and is shifted four hours forward
dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from test_table")
```

Comment: Losing the milliseconds component would suggest that the value may be being inserted as a `DATE` data type rather than a `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought as well.  How do I ensure it gets inserted as a `TIMESTAMP` data type?

Comment: You can do `desc mytable` in sqlplus to see what the columns in the table are.

Comment: I created the table.  The column is a timestamp.  What I’m having trouble with is keeping the milliseconds when I write the data from R.

Comment: What is your db time zone? The hour offset may be due to a difference between your local time zone and the db time zone.

Comment: Both the database and R are set to eastern time.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the timestamp value as a string and convert it in the SQL:

```
insert into test_table (datetime) values (TO_TIMESTAMP(:1, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF'))
```

Pass your parameter as a string which matches the format in the `TO_TIMESTAMP` function, e.g.

```
"22-MAR-2019 17:46:57.123456"
```

and change the date format to whatever you're comfortable with.

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately this won't work since I'm using bind variables.  I need to pass the timestamp value using dbBind and have it recognize it as a timestamp instead of a date.